# In job interviews, how should I handle being on a team at my last job for a very short time?

Tags: job-search, job-change

I recently got transferred to a different team in the same company. I have been here for 2 months now but do not find this position challenging. So I decided to look for other opportunities.

Is it ok not to mention this to the current team and say that I have been working in the previous team in my resume? Would it cause problems for me later, like during a background check? How should I handle this in interviews?

The following are the reasons I feel not to mention:

1. I have not spent considerable amount of time in this team to mention in the resume.
2. A quick shift again would make people raise eye brows.

Comment: If your previous position with the company is significantly longer, this seems reasonable.  Especially if you're looking to do what you did in your previous spot, and not the current new one.  Your resume should be targeted for what you like.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes my earlier spot was longer. I was wondering if it would cause problems in background checks.

Comment: Not actually. But there is a small catch. The company are having two offices in the country which are treated as two different entities. I got a transfer from office A to office B. This process was treated as a transfer with all records in place. My job title has not change. I am worried if this transfer would cause an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most background checks don't go into that great of detail.

They want to know what company you worked for; when you worked for them; and if you were fired. Mot companies will only provide dates of employment and possibly job title. Some will provide salary information if the request is to verify income to determine if you qualify for a loan.

Which team you worked for will never come up during a background investigation. If you worked on one team longer you might be expected to have more words associated with the skills and results for that team. There i no telling which team will have the better buzz word, or technology that will interest a future employer.

Hiring managers realize that sometimes you end up in a position that doesn't seem as strong because of what is available when a previous project comes to an end. Little detours within the same company are not something to worry about.

The one place you do need to mention all your teams is within the internal company resume. When applying for internal positions you need to be accurate regarding who is your current manager/team. If you don't keep it up to date you may miss out on opportunities, or confuse the issue when they are trying to evaluate your skill set.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it ok not to mention this to the current team and say that I have
>   been working in the previous team in my resume?

If your title stayed the same when you changed teams, it's reasonable to avoid any team-specific mentions on your resume.

While interviewers will care about your title, the company, and the kind of work you performed, resume readers seldom care which team you worked on, or the specific office in which you worked.

And as mhoran_psprep points out background checks seldom care, either.

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum - No, you do not have to mention it in your resume, or even at an interview if it is not asked.

However, **there is no reason to lie about it either**.  Your reason for leaving is not unreasonable, and if for some reason they ask if you were part of a team/teams, and you must mention being transferred to another team for a short time towards the end of your work, then be honest.  You don't have to explain why you left after being transferred to anther team, but you don't have to hide it if teamwork happens to come up as part of an interview.

Basically, it is the employer's job to ask questions to discover the depth of their prospective employee, and it is **your** job to explain to the prospective employer anything they ask, but nothing beyond that is required.